# Menus in certian sections

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-navigation

I am taking over a site and need to break up the navigation onto smaller menus for a particular section. Can someone point me to a tutorial, reference, or blog that can show me how to assign menus to sections of the site?

For example:

When you go to mysite.org/divisions it shows the main sidebar navigation 'Navigation' but when you click a link to mysite.org/divisions/spinal-cord-injury-program, the main sidebar navigation is replaced with a different menu 'Spinal Cord Injury Program'. Then anything inside this section '/divisions/spinal-cord-injury-program/....' uses that new menu.

Thanks, still kinda new to all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are searching for a documentation then see this [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/menu), it may help you.

And you need to see the [block documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/block) too for assigning these menu.